# How did a photo magically appear in the iphone contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I am not wise to the ways of apple.  I've had an iphone for about 6 months, and this is the first time I noticed this occurring.

I created a new contact by directly entering it into  the Contacts app on the phone. 
A little while later, I saw that this new contact has a photo attached to it.

I did not specify that photo. It appears to be the correct photo.

Where did it come from?

---

I have the phone configured to sync with a GMail Contacts list, from work. 
Is that where it comes from?

If someone else entered my name into their contacts list, would they get my picture?  How would I set it up so that they do?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial guess that it's Google Contacts is right - if you've set it up to sync with Google Contacts, it'll pull down the same contact photos as you have in Google Contacts, and it works both ways (assign a photo on iPhone, syncs back up to Google Contacts).

If you've got a contact photo set in Google+ or the like, it'll pull that photo automatically, so that's the photo which'll appear to others.

Comment: The same is true for Exchange integration. Contact images put into the Outlook local contact list show up on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable [iOS 6's Facebook Integration](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#facebook)? It will grab updated contact information and pictures from anyone in your contacts you have on Facebook if you enable the Contacts syncing.

Comment: nope - it's IOS 4 !